# FlipView and a collection of images

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I want to work with a flipview with 2 pages,in each page four buttons,in each button I want to put a different image from 8 images,I work on a windows universal app,I tried this code :
I have tried with this code to put in every page of flipView only 4 buttons
xaml :

```
 <FlipView x:Name="flipView1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="642" Background="Transparent"  d:DataContext="{Binding Source={d:DesignInstance Type=local:ButtonImages, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"   ItemsSource="{Binding SampleItems}">
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="#2c3389" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="22,24,25,10" >
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Background="#2c3389" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="22,24,25,10">
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Background="#2c3389" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="22,0,25,27" >
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="#2c3389" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="22,0,25,27" >
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}"/>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        </FlipView>
```

I have created a class named "ButtonImages" that contains images URIs:

```
public class SampleItem
{
    public string ImageUri { get; set; }
}

public class ButtonImages
{
    public List<SampleItem> SampleItems { get; set; }

        public ButtonImages()
        {
            SampleItems = new List<SampleItem>();

            SampleItems.Add(new SampleItem()
            {

                ImageUri = "images/bar.png"
            });

            SampleItems.Add(new SampleItem()
            {

                ImageUri = "images/cuisine.png"
            });
            ...... //the rest of 8 images list
        }
    }
```

then I have used a Datacontext in my MainPage.xmal.cs constructor to call the images and put them in every button in the flipview pages:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.DataContext = new ButtonImages();
    this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

what I get as a result is 8 pages not 2 pages,each page contains 4 buttons with the same image,miss I any thing??
thanks a lot for help

Comment: What your code does: You have an object of type ButtonInages, which just contains a list with 8 images... As you set that as your DataContext, you just get the 8 pages in the FlipView... And then you bind all your images to the same variable. So how could they be different. Please start by rethinking what you bind to: What is is itemssource (type and actual value) and what do you bind your images to...

Comment: thanks Kai for your reply,when I debug,I get all the images in the SampleItems list,the problem is I don't know how can I access to each value from this list and show it as a ButtonContent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bind images in buttons in a FlipView windows app store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143971/bind-images-in-buttons-in-a-flipview-windows-app-store)